# How to display a "Calculating" message while a heavy program is running in the background to prevent lag

Tags: javascript, reactjs, optimization

I have this **react** web app i'm working on. In one of the components, I have a program loops through multiple years, gets all the days between them and displays them i.e is a very heavy computation.

But this slows down the page and makes it laggy. Is there a way I can display a "calculating" message while the process runs in the background until it's done.

Here's what the code looks like:

```
class Component extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      days:[]
      ..
    }
  }

  someComplexFunction(){
    // Run the complex function and set the days state
    ..
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.someComplexFunction();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {/* MAP DAYS TO LIST ITEMS */}
        ..
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I'd look at [web workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers) for the computation. They run in a separate thread, so they won't block the UI thread. Combine this with the BusyWrapper below, and you have a winner.

Answer (score 0):

create `isBusy` property which will be true before call and after response was received will become false and will manage calculating process

i used this `https://material-ui.com/api/circular-progress/`

example

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';
import CircularProgress from '@material-ui/core/CircularProgress';

export default class BusyWrapper extends PureComponent {

    render = _ => (
        <section>
            {this.props.isBusy &&
                <div>
                    <CircularProgress
                        thickness={4}
                    />
                </div>
            }
            {this.props.children}
        </section>
    );
}
```

how use

```
<BusyWrapper
   isBusy={this.state.isBusy}
>
   <YourComponent>
</BusyWrapper>
```